# What is best way to achieve a wavy border in a div

Tags: html, css, svg, html5-canvas

Someone knows what is the best way to achieve something like this?

By now I'm using a background image, but I know it is not the best way.

[image: Wavy background]

Comment: mmm i would say with `border-image`

Comment: An idea would be to forget about borders. Clear the CSS on border on the element and add an absolutely positioned `div` in the background hosting an `<svg>`. Using SVG will allow you to create splines using polynomial coefficients.